# Printing data from an OleDbDataReader in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, printing, console

Basically just for debugging purposes i want to print the contents of my OleDbDataReader object to the console, but i am really struggling to find away of doing it. Could someone help me out please. I have no way of testing my sql (well i can in toad for oracle but thats not the point).

Ideally i am going to transfer the contents of this in to an arraylist if they exist in c# (i am new to c# as you may have guessed!)

```
while (myOleDbDataReader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every field in your Sql-Query, you can get the Data with typing

```
String test = myOleDbDataReader["fieldName"].ToString();
```

for example you can print it with:

```
Console.WriteLine(myOleDbDataReader.["fieldName"].ToString());
```

You can try something like this

```
foreach(var item in myOleDbDataReader)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

to print out every included item. (NOT tested!)

**EDIT:**
Forgot that you have to put the `foreach-loop` in your `while(reader.read())`-loop or it won't work...

**EDIT2:**

better Loop:

```
            for (int k = 0; k < reader.FieldCount; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[k].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: it just seems to print System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal for every item

Comment: Look at my edit, I think this will be the solution you were looking for.